# Redirect Custom Page If the Product Count is Zero in a Woocommerce Category

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I Need to Redirect a Custom Page If the Product Count is Zero in a Woocommerce Category Kindly Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are accessing the product categories via one of the taxonomy term pages:

Add this to your `functions.php` file. Make sure you replace `SOME_PATH . '/some-custom-file.php';` with the path to the template you would like to load.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'redirect_on_empty_product_category' );

function redirect_on_empty_product_category( $template ){

  if ( ( $taxonomy_id = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ) && ( $term_id = get_query_var( 'term' ) ) && is_tax( $taxonomy_id, $term_id ) ){

    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_id, $taxonomy_id );

    if ( $term->count === 0 ){
      $page_url = get_permalink($some_post_id);
      echo sprintf('<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "%s" </script>', $page_url);
    }
  }

  return $template;
}
```

Comment: Hi Instead of some template can i redirect to custom page using page id or slug

Comment: Sure, see my edit to your edit, I added `$page_url = get_permalink($some_post_id);` and converted your echo statement to a sprintf for readability. Just make sure `$some_post_id` is a real page id

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add $cat->count to get the count of all products in that category. Hope this helps you out.

```
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

foreach( $product_categories as $cat )  { 
   echo $cat->name.' ('.$cat->count.')'; 
}
```

Thanks